# Top Level Site page not found

Tags: sharepoint-addin, site-collection, site, web-application

I'm trying to make a site collection. When I create one and give it a host header, the URL for the top site it gives me after creating the site collection never works. When I visit the URL, it says page not found. I've tried creating many site collections, but this issue remains. [image]

In the image above, the default site works, but the `http://testapp/` doesn't.

Comment: Is your DNS (or hosts file) set up correctly so that testapp points at your server?

Comment: And, have you create a site collection in the web application? What you are showing us is the list of web applications, not site collections

Comment: @PerJakobsen Yes Jakbosen, I've created the DNS record for the other host headers - http://i.imgur.com/MMdp7ye.png

Comment: @RobertLindgren Hi Robert, yes I've created site collections - http://i.imgur.com/ywh4lVw.png

Comment: But none at the root of your new web app afaik

Comment: @RobertLindgren Yes Robert, none at the root, but at the wildcard path I created. After creating the site collection at the wildcard path, I get the URL, which doesn't work.

Comment: You should always have a site collection at the root (in fact SharePoint is unsupported if you don't)

Comment: @PerJakobsen I've just created a site collection at the root, but still same issue - http://i.imgur.com/PMeDMcQ.png

Comment: Does `ping boys.psu.edu.sa` give the right IP?

Comment: @PerJakobsen It says `could not find host boys.psu.edu.sa`

Comment: Then your DNS (or hosts file) isn't right

Comment: @PerJakobsen Ah, how can I fix it then?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11155/discussion-between-a-rahmanshah-and-per-jakobsen)

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you are missing here is **Host named site collections (HNSC)**. These are special type of site collections available when some organization is much URL specific. 
You can't create a HNSC using central admin. you have to use powershell commands:

```
New-SPSite 'http://portal.contoso.com' -HostHeaderWebApplication (Get-SPWebApplication 'Contoso Sites') -Name 'Portal' -Description 'Customer root' -OwnerAlias 'contoso\administrator' -language 1033 -Template 'STS#0'
```

but you should have host header web application as up and running before running this command. once HNSC is created, you can do the DNS mapping for newly created site collections.

Reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx